# Exclude dependencies when running Clippy

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

I'm trying to run clippy for the first time (I know.. I really should have done it by now eh?) and I am facing some errors.

The project I'm trying to lint depends on Piston and it compiles and runs successfully. However, when I run clippy [as described in the README](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy#as-a-cargo-subcommand-cargo-clippy):

```
rustup run nightly cargo clippy
```

It looks like it starts trying to build Piston and reports errors like this:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `gfx`
  --> /Users/Simon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-    1ecc6299db9ec823/piston2d-gfx_graphics-0.31.2/src/back_end.rs:31:10
   |
31 |     pos: gfx::VertexBuffer<PositionFormat>,
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Use of undeclared type or module `gfx`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module     `gfx`
  --> /Users/Simon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-    1ecc6299db9ec823/piston2d-gfx_graphics-0.31.2/src/back_end.rs:32:12
   |
32 |     color: gfx::VertexBuffer<ColorFormat>,
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Use of undeclared type or module `gfx`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `gfx`
  --> /Users/Simon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/piston2d-gfx_graphics-0.31.2/src/back_end.rs:33:19
   |
33 |     blend_target: gfx::BlendTarget<gfx::format::Srgba8>,
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Use of undeclared type or module `gfx`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `gfx`
  --> /Users/Simon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/piston2d-gfx_graphics-0.31.2/src/back_end.rs:33:36
   |
33 |     blend_target: gfx::BlendTarget<gfx::format::Srgba8>,
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Use of undeclared type or module `gfx`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `gfx`
  --> /Users/Simon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/piston2d-gfx_graphics-0.31.2/src/back_end.rs:34:21
   |
34 |     stencil_target: gfx::StencilTarget<gfx::format::DepthStencil>,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Use of undeclared type or module `gfx`
```

How can I tell clippy to not build Piston and/or lint it? How can I just have it build my project and lint my code?

`cargo build` builds the project successfully from the same folder.

I haven't dug deep into clippy's code, but I assumed it worked off an AST and didn't actually build the binaries... it seems I was incorrect?

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster I didn't know about the <!-- language: --> markers. I learned something!

Comment: Too bad I can't actually help with the real problem :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I tell clippy to not build Piston and/or lint it?

You can't.

Clippy needs to build all dependencies to be able to lint your project. This is because only a few lints run solely on the AST. Most lints run on the HIR and also require type information.

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your error on `piston_window v0.57.0`, but that version pulls in `piston2d-gfx_graphics v0.33.1`, which is newer than the `0.31.2` that you are using. Maybe updating will solve your issues.

Comment: Thanks. I actually never thought to check for an update. I converted to an asterisk for the versions of all of the Piston crates and ran `cargo update` and ... wouldn't you know it... `rustup run nightly cargo clippy` is now returning actual clippy results. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Maybe it could *build* all the dependencies it needed, but have an option to NOT flag warnings/errors outside the project code that you cannot fix?

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie that's the way I assumed it would work, but I can't find any such flag/option for cargo check or cargo clippy, so a 3rd party issue prevents clippy from even checking my local code.   afaict

Comment: @danda - yep, that seems to be the way it is and we just have to live with it.

Answer (score 2):

In [version 1.50 of Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#rust-150), Clippy gained the `--no-deps` option. According to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/clippy/usage.html?highlight=--no-deps#workspaces):

> As with cargo check, this includes dependencies that are members of
> the workspace, like path dependencies. If you want to run Clippy only
> on the given crate, use the --no-deps option like this:
>
> ```
> cargo clippy -p example -- --no-deps
> ```

The command line help for `--no-deps` says:

> Run Clippy only on the given crate, without linting the dependencies